# pip3.7 ubuntu 16 pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, ssl, pip

I'm using gitbash virtualbox and ubuntu 16 and windows 10.  I've installed the python 3.7 package from python.org and before I did that I installed

build-essential 
checkinstall 
libreadline-gplv2-dev 
libcurfsesw5-dev 
libssl-dev 
libsqlite3-dev 
tk-dev 
libgdbm-dev 
libc50-dev 
libbz2-dev 
libffi-dev 
zlib1g-dev

and I can't install any packages with pip3.7.  I read that there are some lines I might need to uncomment in /usr/local/bin/python3.7/Modules but when I try to get into python3.7 I get the error Not a directory, so I can't try that solution.  When I try to install a package with

```
sudo pip3.7 install psycopg2
```

I get these errors:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I've searched everywhere for a fix to this and can't find a solution that works.

is there anything I can try to get this working?

Thanks
Michael

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue myself on Kali 2020.3, and found [this over on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164352/cannot-use-pip-ubuntu-pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl). It worked for me.

1. Install the necessary packages for Python and ssl: `sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`
2. Download and unzip Python from https://www.python.org/ into your Downloads directory.
3. Open terminal in that directory and run: `./configure`
4. Build and install: `sudo make && sudo make install`

Now you should be able to install Python3 packages without TLS/SSL errors, using: `pip3 install package_name`